# Div not going fullscreen properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fullscreen

I am trying to make a div fullscreen, Below is the code used:

```
  if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
  document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
} else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
  document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
} else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
  document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
}
```

where I am replacing document.documentElement by document.getElementById()

It works perfectly fine for firefox but for chrome the fullscreen comes with the div and header and footer.

Any tips on how I can avoid that and make just the div(resized accordingly for fullscreen) come in fullscreen?

Thanks in advance,
Sumit

Comment: Is the div required to cover all the screen area in fullscreen and non-fullscreen mode?

Comment: Yes its very much like youtube video going fullscreen. I want just the div to go fullscreen and not the whole html page. I am able to achieve this via above code in firefox but not in chrome.